Sources on hirhurei aveira
There's a famous Rosh, very short, on the subject of הרהורים, and the mechanics of punishment for bad thoughts alone.  Supposedly, it has opened a rich literature, but my חברותא & I are not finding much.
Here is the brief Rosh on Rosh Hashanah 17b:

א"ר יוחנן אלמלא מקרא כתוב אי אפש לאומרו מלמד שנתעטף הקב"ה כשליח ציבור והראה למשה בסיני ואמר לו כל זמן שישראל חוטאים יעשו לפני כסדר הזה ואני מוחל להם. "ה' ה'" אני הוא קודם שיחטא האדם אני הוא אחר שיחטא האדם. וא"ת מה צריך האדם למדת רחמים קודם שיחטא. וי"ל אע"פ שגלוי וידוע לפניו שסופו לחטוא מתנהג עמו במדת רחמים באשר הוא שם. אי נמי קודם שיחטא בע"ז. ואע"פ שכבר חשב לעובדה ומחשבת ע"ז הקב"ה מצרפה למעשה (קידושין לט:). כדכתיב (יחזקאל יד) "למען תפוש את בית ישראל בלבם" אפ"ה מתנהג עמו במדת הרחמים קודם שיחטא  וכשיחטא מצרף המחשבה עם המעשה.

There's also a long & fascinating Rabbeinu Bachye on Devarim 29:18 who discusses the same subject.
And there's a short ChID"A in his ספר, פסח עינים that picks up the topic.
That's all I've found thus far.  Where is there more discussion to be found on this topic: how we are punished for thoughts alone versus our actions... or for thoughts on top of our actions?

related: Are thoughts of sin punished halachically?


It seems that the ideas stem from Gemara Yoma 29a


הִרְהוּרֵי עֲבֵירָה קָשׁוּ מֵעֲבֵירָה, וְסִימָנָיךְ: רֵיחָא דְבִישְׂרָא. שִׁילְהֵי דְקַיְיטָא קְשֵׁי מִקַּיְיטָא, וְסִימָנָיךְ: תַּנּוּרָא שְׁגִירָא.
Thoughts of transgression are worse than transgression itself, and your mnemonic is the odor of meat. The smell of roasting meat is more appetizing than actually eating the meat. The heat of the end of summer is more oppressive than the heat of the summer itself, and your mnemonic is a heated oven. After an oven has been heated several times in the course of a day, lighting it again, even slightly, will produce powerful heat. So too, at the end of the summer, since everything is hot, the heat is more oppressive.

There are many commentaries on this one.

Gemara Horayos 10b teaches Lot got into trouble with his daughters because he offered them to anshei S'dom. (It's too long to  paste here). There are other cases.

It is mentioned by Ben Yehoyada on Yoma 38b and maybe some others:

או יובן הענין כהך מעשה של לוֹט שאם לא היתה אשתו נעשית נְצִיב מֶלַח לא היה חוטא עם בנותיו אף על פי שהוא חטא בלא דעת כלל אך כיון שמקודם היה לו הרהור תאוה רעה כמו שאמרו בהוריות (הוריות י:) על פסוק (בראשית יג, י) 'וַיִּשָּׂא לוֹט אֶת עֵינָיו' לכך לא סייעו מן השמים שלא תהיה אשתו נְצִיב מֶלַח כדי דממילא לא היה נופל בחטא זה של בנותיו והבא להטהר כגון יִשַׁי שכונתו לשם שמים כאשר תבע את שפחתו סייעו אותו שיהיה נזקק לאשתו ולא לשפחתו.


I also heard an idea from one rav in a private conversation that the reason why the lives of pre-flood people were long because they worked on purifying their thoughts, which is a very difficult task as they succumbed to what they tried purify themselves from.

Rabbeinu Bachya Vayikra 6:2 says that korban Olah atones for improper thoughts:



ויש שאינו נאכל לא לכהנים ולא לבעלים, והוא קרבן עולה שאין לבני אדם בו שום חלק אלא כולו להקב"ה, וזהו לשון כליל, וקרבן זה של עולה הוא הנכבד שבכל הקרבנות כלן, וכן מוכיח הלשון שאמר היא העולה, הוסיף לומר היא העולה למעלת הקרבן וחשיבותו, וכן (יחזקאל י׳:ט״ו) היא החיה אשר ראיתי. גם פרי מעשיה גדול שמכפרת על הרהור הלב, כמו שאמר באיוב (איוב א׳:ה׳) והעלה עולות מספר כלם כי אמר איוב אולי חטאו בני וברכו אלהים בלבבם, וזהו לשון עולה שמכפרת על העולה על הרוח. והיה קרבן עולה קרב כל הלילה עד הבקר לפי שהאדם מחשב בלילה וחוטא ביום, הוא שאמר הנביא (מיכה ב׳:א׳) חושבי און ופועלי רע על משכבותם באור הבקר יעשוה, ועל כן צותה התורה שתהיה כפרה בזמן העברה. ולפי שעקר העברה היא ברוח היה הכל כליל באש ושב אל הרוח, ולא היה רשות לדבר גופני ליהנות ממנו, זהו הענין האחד.
הענין השני גודל חיוב הנברא לעבוד את בוראו, דבר ידוע כי האדם צריך שיהיה נכנע ושפל להקב"ה בעמדו בתפלה לפניו או בעשותו מצוה או אחד מיתר העבודות הקלות או החמורות, שיתהדר בהם לכבוד הש"י, ושלא יחוס על כבוד עצמו, אלא שיכיר בעצמו כי הבשר והדם דל הוא ואין ידו משגת לחובה העצומה, וראוי לו להכנע ולהשפיל עצמו, כענין שכתוב באברהם (בראשית י״ח:כ״ז) ואנכי עפר ואפר, והמלך דוד ע"ה אמר (תהילים ט״ו:ד׳) נבזה בעיניו נמאס וז"ש בכאן:
There are also some sacrifices of which no part may be eaten by either the Priest or the owner. This is first and foremost the sacrifice discussed here, the עולה, burnt-offering, concerning which the Torah stipulated that all of it is to be burnt up on the Altar. This is the meaning of the word כליל, (verse 15). This burnt-offering is the most highly regarded of all the offerings and that is why the Torah emphasises that היא העולה, “it is the upwards striving offering, etc.” Similarly, in Ezekiel 10,20 when the prophet describes היא החיה אשר ראיתי, “this is the chayah which I saw.” the extra word היא shows that of a variety of similar offerings or beings the one singled out with this extra word is considered the most elevated, the most highly regarded. The burnt-offering also possesses the quality of atoning for sinful thoughts as we know from Job, 1,5 where we are told that Job would offer such burnt-offerings after family gatherings during the various feasts in respect of each member of his family. [Had the offering been in respect of deeds committed, he would not have had to do this on behalf of everyone. Ed.] According to Ezekiel 20,32 this offering was in respect of sinful thoughts. Seeing man entertains these kinds of thoughts mostly at night the offering may remain on the altar all night long to counteract the thoughts of the person at night which are not carried out until daytime on whose behalf it had been brought. The prophet Michah 2,1 phrases it thus: “Ah, those who plan iniquity and design evil on their beds; when morning comes they do it, for they have the power.” This is why the Torah commanded that the atonement should occur at the time the iniquity is being committed. Seeing that in essence the sin was insubstantive, i.e. only in the mind, the offering is to dissolve entirely in the wind, the smoke rising into the air. The animal, so to speak, returns to the regions of the spirit it came from. No substantive part of the world, i.e. a body, is allowed to derive any benefit from this offering. This is one aspect of the burnt-offering.
The second aspect is the lesson of how important it is for the creature to serve his Creator. It is a well known fact that man has to relate to his G’d from a position of being submissive, humble. One needs to demonstrate this both while praying and while performing any of the other relatively easy commandments or even the difficult commandments. One needs to remain aware that performance of such commandments is not meant to be a “feather in our cap,” but is meant to enhance G’d’s glory. We need to remain constantly aware that our flesh is weak and that it is not capable of fulfilling the commandments in the manner they ought to be performed. We have to learn from Avraham who described himself as עפר ואפר, “dust and ashes,” though he had already offered his very life for Hashem (Genesis 18,27). King David expressed a similar sentiment when he said (Psalms 15,4) “man must be contemptible in his own eyes.” [He must feel that he has done less than a fraction of what is expected of him. Ed.]


The pasuk Vayikra 6:6 based on Tikunei Zohar 73a


קָם סָבָא חַד מִבָּתַר טוּלָא (כותלא), וְאָמַר רַבִּי רַבִּי בּוֹצִינָא קַדִּישָׁא, קוּם אַדְלֵיק שְׁרַגָּא דְאִיהִי מִצְוָה, שְׁכִינְתָּא קַדִּישָׁא, דַּעֲלָהּ אִתְּמַר (ויקרא ו ו) אֵשׁ תָּמִיד תּוּקַד עַל הַמִּזְבֵּחַ לֹא תִכְבֶּה, וַעֲלָהּ אִתְּמַר (שמות כז כ) לְהַעֲלֹת נֵר תָּמִיד, נֵר יהו"ה אִתְקְרִיאַת וַדַּאי, אוֹר דְּנָהִיר בֵּיהּ נִשְׁמַת אָדָם, קוּם אַדְלֵיק בָּהּ.
One older person stood up from behind a wall, and said: Rebbe my teacher, The Holy Light, come and light candles, for that is a Mitzva (commandment), on that it is said: An everlasting fire shall be kept burning on the altar, it should not be extinguished. And, on that it is also said: To light the eternal flame. This is surely the light of the divine, the light that shines within the soul of every person. Come, light it with her.

is used as a segula against evil thoughts or clear one's mind when failing to concentrate during Amidah. R'Frand has a lecture "A Segula from Eliyahu from Evil Thoughts" where he mentions the last two and attributes the idea for the second to R'Moshe Cordovero.
